# C - how to split a matrix in 4

Tags: c, matrix

What`s the easiest method to split a matrix in 4?
I have a nxn matrix, where n is multiple of 4;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4H2m.png

[image]

```
____________________
|        |         |
|        |         |
|  1st   |  2nd    |
|        |         |
|--------+----------
|        |         |
|  4th   |  3rd    |
|        |         |
|________|_________|
```

I don`t need to make a new matrix, only to get the ranges of i,j that refer to that new matrix;

Comment: Do you need four different  2D arrays??

Comment: This looks eerily familiar...

Comment: Please don't use images for such trivial little bits of stuff; include it in the question.  Then explain more thoroughly what you're after.

Comment: AHA!  'deleted by Jon Lajoie 26 mins ago'

Comment: Define a typedef struct that represents a sub-matrix.  Declare 4 of them.  Fill in the member values with some code.  Break after the loading and inspect the values with your debugger or printf them out.  Fix stuff.  Rinse. wash, repeat until the values are correct to your spec.

Comment: Note well that 'easiest' usually does not mean 'in the smallest number of code lines', or 'looks like it should be fastest', or 'uses least memory'.  It usually means 'what is easiest to test and debug'.  Use intermediate temp vars, split up all compound expressions etc.  Make your code debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

1 st quadrant range of indices 0 - i/2 and 0 - j/2

2nd 0 - i/2 and j/2+1 - j

3rd i/2+1 - i and j/2+1 - j

4th i/2+1 - i and 0 - j/2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

1. First matrix should go from: (0,0) - (n/2-1,n/2-1)
2. Second matrix should go from: (0,n/2) - (n/2-1,n-1)
3. 3th matrix should go from: (n/2,n/2) - (n-1,n-1)
4. 4th matrix should go from: (n/2,0) - (n-1,n/2-1)